# Bash, always echo in conditional statement

Tags: bash

This may turn out to be more of a thought exercise, but I am trying to echo a newline after some command I'm executing within a conditional.  For example, I have:

```
if ssh me@host [ -e $filename ] ; then
  echo "File exists remotely"
else
  echo "Does not exist remotely"
fi
```

And want to throw in an echo after the `ssh` command regardless of the outcome.  The reason is formatting; that way  a newline will exist after the prompt for password for ssh.

**First Try**

```
if ssh me@host [ -e $filename ] && echo ; then
```

Because `&& echo` would not change the conditional outcome, but bash would not execute `echo` if `ssh` returned false.  Similarly,

```
if ssh me@host [ -e $filename ] || (echo && false) ; then
```

Does not work because it will short-circuit if `ssh` returns true.

An answer to the problem would be

```
ssh me@host [ -e $filename ]
result=$?
echo
if [ $result == 0 ] ; then
```

but was wondering if there was some similar conditional expression to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this would work

```
if foo && echo || ! echo; then
```

I'd prefer putting the whole thing into a function

```
function addecho() {
    "$@" # execute command passed as arguments (including parameters)
    result= $? # store return value
    echo
    return $result # return stored result
}

if addecho foo; then
```

Comment: I agree, that's probably the cleanest looking solution.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
 if ssh me@host [ -e $filename ]  && echo || echo; then
```

I have not thought about precedence order of && and || and surely putting some parenthesis would help, but like that it works already... you get the echo both when ssh fails and when it succeeds...

Comment: This is the way I like to do it. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 2):

Add the "echo" before the filename test

```
if ssh me@host "echo; [ -e $filename ]"; then
  echo "File exists remotely"
else
  echo "Does not exist remotely"
fi
```